# Where can I find a list of Demons for Polaris?

Tags: polaris

Just looking for names, actually.  There's a bunch of nice ones in the rulebook, but I'm not clear on what the naming conventions are.  They seem vaguely Aztec-myth-y in origin (Etzlitotec, Four Birds, The Engine of Fire), but I want a list of names specifically for the Mistaken rather than just a list of names from Aztec mythology.  A fan created list is acceptable, as long as it is high quality.  I'm looking for something analogous to the example name tables for PCs given on pages 120-129 of the rulebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't one.

Etzlitotec means "blood goddess" in Nahuatl (the Aztec language) but she's not a real goddess.

Generally I name them:

- Things from world mythology which are not already stars, ideally either slightly made up (as above) or not anything anyone worships. (Etzlitotec, Leviathan)
- Descriptive names, which just say what the demon is (The hot wind of summer, four birds.)
- Names of people from other games I've played.

(edit: Nahuatl is the language, Aztec is the empire. Oops.)

Comment: Welcome to site!  Please take a look at our [help] and [tour] when you have the time.  I hope to see you around more, especially since we have so few Polaris player here :)  You've already got enough rep to join us in [chat], btw.

Comment: Yeah, Ben, there are so few Polaris players around here. :P

Comment: I had this saved to answer when I got home from my day, but I can't give any better answer than the man himself. I'll only add, I like to find meaning of names from around the world and use the name that means the cool thing I associate with the Mistaken.